# Java LinkedList speed advantage

Tags: java, performance, insertion

Was trying to figure out the real speed advantage of LinkedList in different cases. As it is said in the lecture - LinkedList is way faster while adding new item in the beginning/middle.
But my experiment shows me,that it is not true. Insertion in the middle doubles the resources expenses (slow index positioning+fast insertion). What is really fast - insertion in the beginning (zero index)

```
public class Example{
    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> ast = new ArrayList<>();

        estimateGet(lst,"LinkedList getting by index");
        estimateGet(ast,"ArrayList getting by index");

        estimateInsert(lst,"LinkedList inserting in the middle");
        estimateInsert(ast,"ArrayList inserting in the middle");

        estimateInsertZero(lst,"LinkedList inserting in the beginning");
        estimateInsertZero(ast,"ArrayList inserting in the beginning");
    }


    public static void estimateGet(List<Integer> lst,String message){
        Date begin = new Date();
        int a = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
            a = lst.get(i);
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(message+" - "+(end.getTime()-begin.getTime()));
    }

    public static void estimateInsert(List<Integer> lst,String message){
        Date begin = new Date();
        int a = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
            lst.add(i,i);
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(message+" - "+(end.getTime()-begin.getTime()));
    }

    public static void estimateInsertZero(List<Integer> lst,String message){
        Date begin = new Date();
        int a = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
            lst.add(0,i);
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println(message+" - "+(end.getTime()-begin.getTime()));
    }
}
```

These are my results:

LinkedList adding - 5

ArrayList adding - 3

LinkedList getting by index - 3492

ArrayList getting by index - 2

LinkedList inserting in the middle - 6896

ArrayList inserting in the middle - 940

LinkedList inserting in the beginning - 5

ArrayList inserting in the beginning - 2420

Am i getting it correct? The only case LinkedList is useful for - is insertion in the beginning?

Comment: There are many things wrong with the approach. I would start out converting the benchmarks to JMH which takes care of warming up the JIT and dead code elimination.

Comment: Relevant: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: There is almost never a benefit to choose `LinkedList` over `ArrayList`. In almost all cases, `ArrayList` will 1) consume (a lot) less memory, and 2) perform (a lot) better.